# Optimizing composite std::functions

Tags: c++, optimization, functional-programming, c++11, mathematical-optimization

Is it possible to optimize a series of "glued together" `std::function`s and/or is there any implementation that attempts to do this?

What I mean is most easily expressed mathematically: say I want to make a `std::function` that is a function of a function:

```
f(x,y,z) = x^2 * y^3 * z^4
g(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z) / (x*y^2)
```

Is there a way for an STL/compiler implementor to optimize away parts of the arithmetic is calling a function object of `g`, created from a function object of `f`?

This would be a kind of symbolic simplification of the functions, but because this is a `std::function`, it would have to be spotted on a machine level.

Due to this being an optimization, which takes time, and probably isn't free (in clock cycles and/or memory), it probably isn't allowed by the Standard? It leans very close to a language that is typically ran through a VM. (I'm thinking LLVM more than Java here, with runtime optimizations).

EDIT: In order to make the discussion "more useful", here's a short code snippet (I understand a lambda is not a `std::function`, but a lambda can be stored in a `std::function`, so assuming `auto` below means `std::function<T>` with the appropriate `T` will express perfectly what I meant above):

```
auto f = [](const double x, const double y, const double z){ return x*x*y*y*y*z*z*z*z; };
auto g = [](const double c, const double y, const double z){ return f(x,y,z)/(x*y*y); };
```

A "trivial" compiler would make `g` equivalent to

```
double g(const double x, const double y, const double z){ return x*x*y*y*y*z*z*z*z/(x*y*y); }
```

While an optimized `std::function` could make it (mathematically and in every other sense correct!):

```
double g( const double x, const double y, const double z){ return x*y*z*z*z*z; }
```

Note that although I'm talking about mathematical functions here, similar transformations could be made for functions in the general sense, but that would take more introspection, which means overhead.

I can see this being very important when designing mathematical and physics simulations, where the generality of compositing existing library functions into user-case functions, with all the usual mathematical simplifications could make for a nice method of expressive, yet performant calculation software.

Comment: Optimization is allowed by the standard.  There is nothing in the standard to say "thou shalt not optimize".  (Well, there are some caveats around `volatile` in particular, but not for the code you are asking about.)  It is perhaps more a question of whether the compiler can safely make the optimization, and whether it is worth the compiler writers' time to look for the optimization.

Comment: I don't think it's forbidden by the standard, because it takes time. But it probably is forbidden, because it changes the semantics. For x == 0 or y == 0, the unoptimized version gives NaN, the optimized would simple return 0.

Comment: I would guess this kind of optimization is possible with `constexpr` functions.

Comment: @Henrik so you're saying g(x, y, z) = 0 with x=0 is not a solution in the unoptimized version? :)

Comment: @duedl0r: yes, if x, y and z are of type float or double, I would expect g(0,0,0) to calculate 0 / 0 and thus return NaN.

Comment: Well, purely mathematically speaking, `g(0,y,z) = 0`, because you're not dividing by 0 anymore (!). That was kind of my point with these optimisations, a kind of mathematical simplification if you wish...

Comment: I don't understand what it has to do with `std::function` (and c++0x). You need to show the code to make discussion useful.

Comment: @rubenvb: Really pedantically speaking, you are only allowed to cancel `x/x = 1` when `x` is non-zero. What is true is that the function `x -> x/x` has removable singularity at 0 with limit 1.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: *really* pedantically speaking, you can only write `1/x` if `x` is not 0, but `x/x` is as good as anything even when x=0, because the limit of `x/x` of x->0 is still well-defined and the function is continuous and smooth as you can find one...

Comment: I suggest you remove reference to `std::function` from your question, not only because lambda is not `std::function`, but because the complications for compiler using `std::function` make the answer a definite **NO**. And even using lambdas is unnecessary complication. The most straightforward way is to write two inlined functions.

Comment: @Gene: although the code example contains a lambda, it is almost inevitable to use `std::function` to pass around lambda's, by which I mean that an algebraic system wouldn't use one without the other and have to be able to optimize both. Nowhere in the standard does it state that a lambda can't be a `std::function`, it's just hard in several cases (variable capture), but never forbidden. Encouraged even, I would say, seeing that a lambda needs to be convertible into a `std::function`.

Comment: @rubenvb: the question has really nothing to do with lambdas, or std::function. Lambdas are implemented as closures, it's in the standard. And though lambdas can be assigned to std::function, it's not their common use.

Comment: @rubenvb The fact that `std::function` would be inevitable is a complete red-herring: using a `main` function is also inevitable, but the last place to look for optimization in your scenario is in `main`. An algebraic system would **definitely** not want to use `std::function` since type-erasure gets rid of important information (as the name suggests, types); *client-code* would make use of it but not *library-code*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why you leave the optimizing to the compiler. They're algebraically equivalent but *not* equivalent due to FP imprecision. Your two versions of g would yield subtly different answers, which could be very important if called in an inner loop- not to mention the behavioural difference if x, y, z was 0.

Secondly, as the contents of `function` are unknown until run-time, there's no way the compiler could perform such optimizations as it doesn't have the data it needs.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is allowed to optimize in specific allowed cases, or if the optimized code behaves "as if" it were the unopotimized code.

In this case not only would `x` or `y` being 0 change the results, but if `f` overflowed, or the data types were floating point or user defined the results could change as a result of such optimization. Thus I suspect in practice you'll never see it happen and would have to (if possible) compose a combined function at compile time (presumably using templates).

Comment: Note that, at least in C, if undefined behavior such as overflow or division by zero occurs, then the program is allowed to do anything—and as a consequence, optimizations are free to *ignore* those cases, such as (not that any compiler necessarily does this, nor is it necessarily an optimization) optimizing `x*x + x*y + y*y` to `(x+y)*(x+y)`.

Comment: undefined behavior is not a side effect to prevent optimization, it's a license to a compiler to do (almost) anything :-)

Comment: @Antal:  Except that those two aren't equivalent ;-) (`(x+y)*(x+y)` is equivalent to `x*x + 2*x*y + y*y`).  In addition, it is only _actual_ overflow that yields undefined behavior, not _potential_ overflow:  if the compiler does perform some sort of arithmetic transformation, it must ensure that for any inputs into the original expression that yield valid results, the transformed expression yields the same valid results.